# Building and flashing openthread on a Simplelink cc2640r2f ( Launchxl-CC2640R2)

Tags: openthread

I recently aquired a launchxl-cc2640r2 board with a CC2640R2F MCU. I want to build a network using Openthread. I have tried with no success the instructions found on https://github.com/openthread/openthread/tree/master/examples/platforms/cc2650  which so far were the closest I have found on the web to deploying openthread on the CC2640R2F  (CC26xx family) .

Question: Does somebody have some experience with building and flashing openthread on a CC2640R2F MCU and could offer me some help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CC2640R2F is a BLE only Wireless MCU. It is not able to operate in IEEE 802.15.4 mode. The ROM image is optimized for BLE 4.2 operation.

The CC2650 Wireless MCU is able to run OpenThread, but its functionality is limited because of the available Flash. It is recommended that you use the CC2652R1 (http://www.ti.com/tool/LAUNCHXL-CC26X2R1). This device has all the necessary space for OpenThread to run.